# how do you do @Config and @Bean on not spring boot applications

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations

How do you do @Configurationand @Bean on non Springboot applications? sample below:

```
@Configuration
public class CoreBeansConfig {

    @Bean
    public YelpService yelpServiceImpl(YelpRestGateway yelpRestGateway){
        return new YelpServiceImpl(yelpRestGateway);
    }

}
```

I am working on a non-spring application. After injecting (@Inject) a class to my another class, the program won't call my class anymore. Confirmed it by adding a breakpoint. Seems like my class can't be found, so I'm trying to define it as a bean. Hence, my question above.

Comment: I think you cannot create bean to non-spring boot application. But Do you want to make this class as Singleton ?

Comment: nope. this is just a sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. Dependency Injection relies on objects creation and management by the underlying container. In JEE applications it may be JBoss, WebSphere or WebLogic. For Spring-Boot applications under the hood, it is Tomcat. Without such container, you can't have this Inversion of Control mechanism.